# Why am I getting KeyErrors when accessing multiple rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to write the following condition to map `MARKET_STATES.OPENING_AUCTION`, however I am getting `KeyError: (False, False, False)` when I run the following:

```
market_info_df.loc[market_info_df['issue_status' == '10', 'market_phase' == '0',
                                          'trading_state' == '  '].iloc[0]] = MARKET_STATES.OPENING_AUCTION
```

Two questions:

- What is it that the query does? My understanding is that using `iloc[0]` it finds the first instance where the three columns at the values stated. But then it maps something to `MARKET_STATES.OPENING_AUCTION` or?
- How can I write a condition like the above where if the 3 columns match the values, then for the first occurrence of this, map another columns (say `trade_type`) to `MARKET_STATES.OPENING_AUCTION`?

Here is an example:

e.g:

```
row  issue_status  market_phase  trading_state                  trade_type
 0        20           0              '  '         ->        
 1        10           0              '  '         ->        OPENING_AUCTION
 2        20           0              '  '         ->       
 3        10           0              '  '         ->       
 4        10           0              '  '         ->       
 5        10           0              '  '         ->
```

Comment: Since you say your exact dataframe isn't relevant and too big for the question, you should create a toy dataframe as part of a [mre].

Comment: Thanks Pranav- I found a way to add a simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer your second question first:

> How can I write a condition like the above where if the 3 columns match the values, then for the first occurrence of this, map another columns (say `trade_type`) to `MARKET_STATES.OPENING_AUCTION`?

```
market_info_df = pd.DataFrame({'issue_status': {0: 20, 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 10, 4: 10, 5: 10},
 'market_phase': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0},
 'trading_state': {0: '  ', 1: '  ', 2: '  ', 3: '  ', 4: '  ', 5: '  '}})
```

Any time you want to combine multiple conditions, remember that you need a *logical and* or *logical or* operation on those conditions.

When you have three conditions and you want to select rows where *all* of them are `True`, you need to *and* all the conditions. So in your case you'd need to do

```
mask = (market_info_df['issue_status'] == 10) & (market_info_df['market_phase'] == 0) & (market_info_df['trading_state'] == '  ')
```

To get a boolean mask that tells you which rows fulfill all those conditions. The `&` operator is overloaded by pandas to do the element-wise logical and for multiple `Series` objects. The parentheses are needed to override [python's operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) which puts `&` before `==`

<sup>Note: My dataframe contains *integers* in the `issue_status` and `market_phase` columns, which is why I compare against integers e.g. `market_info_df['issue_status'] == 10`. If your columns contain strings (as your code would indicate), compare against strings (`market_info_df['issue_status'] == "10"`)</sup>

Next, you want to set those rows for the `"trade_type"` column, so you'd do:

```
market_info_df.loc[mask, "trade_type"] = "OPENING_AUCTION"
```

Which sets those only rows:

```
   issue_status  market_phase trading_state       trade_type
0            20             0                            NaN
1            10             0                OPENING_AUCTION
2            20             0                            NaN
3            10             0                OPENING_AUCTION
4            10             0                OPENING_AUCTION
5            10             0                OPENING_AUCTION
```

Now, we can use [`idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to get the index of the max value of the `mask`. Since this mask only contains `True` and `False` values, the first occurrence of the `True` value is the one that is returned. If we do this instead of setting all values of `mask`, we get:

```
market_info_df.loc[mask.idxmax(), "trade_type"] = "OPENING_AUCTION"
```

which gives:

```
   issue_status  market_phase trading_state       trade_type
0            20             0                            NaN
1            10             0                OPENING_AUCTION
2            20             0                            NaN
3            10             0                            NaN
4            10             0                            NaN
5            10             0                            NaN
```

---

As for your first question:

> What is it that the query does? My understanding is that using `iloc[0]` it finds the first instance where the three columns at the values stated. But then it maps something to `MARKET_STATES.OPENING_AUCTION` or?

I have no idea what that code is supposed to do. The code inside the brackets i.e.:

```
'issue_status' == '10', 'market_phase' == '0', 'trading_state' == '  '
```

compares the string `"issue_status"` to the string `"10"` (which unsurprisingly is `False`) and so on, and returns a tuple that contains three `False`s.

Then, `market_info_df[False, False, False]` tries to find the element in the dataframe at the `False, False, False` key, and throws the error when it fails to do so.

Comment: Amazing, thank you @Pranav ; what if I want to map the first occurance to `OPENING_AUCTION` as you have done above, but all subsequent occurances to `CONTINUOUS_AUCTION`?

Comment: @Patrick I just realized you wanted to change only the _first_ occurrence. I've updated my answer.

Comment: And is it easy to map the rest of the instances to `CONTINUOUS_AUCTION`?

Comment: @PatrickChong yes! I'd suggest you set the entire column to `market_info_df["trade_type"] = "CONTINUOUS_ACTION"` first, and then overwrite the rows that you need with `"OPENING_AUCTION"` the way I showed above.

Comment: That's so clever, thank you

Comment: When I run the query above it overrides the existing rows- is there a way to simply update rather than override rows that do not meet the condition?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that @PatrickChong. What rows are overridden?

Comment: Sorry ignore me Pranav, it works now. 

Is there a way to mark the `last` and `second_last` instance with something? I imagine it may involve `idxmin`?

Comment: I am struggling quite a lot with this- would be very grateful if you could help! :)

Comment: I managed to get it for the `last` occurance by flipping the mask around with [::-1] . But getting the second last value is tough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250242/discussion-between-pranav-hosangadi-and-patrick-chong).